# Непонятная служба в автозагрузке

Tags: windows, автозагрузка, службы

У меня такая проблема - недавно я устанавливал обновление на одно своё приложение, и у меня после устанвки в автозагрузке появилась программа "Realtek HD Audio", а она у меня не установлена (смотрел в панели управления).
И, когда я выключаю программу, она обратно включается [image: Вот в автозагрузке]

Кроме того, во вкладке `Процессы` появилось несколько таких процессов - [image: Процессы]

Не знаю что это. И, на последок скажу, что когда я открываю `Диспетчер задач`, память бывает нагружена почти до 100%, и постепенно падает. А иногда Дисп. задач вообще выключается!

Comment: Ну а самое банальное, проверить на вирусы не пробовали?

Comment: Антивирусник ничего не показал, также пробовал CCleaner pro. Но, погуглив я понял что это вирус, а как его убрать - я не знаю.

Comment: Скачайте программы на проверку вирусов, я штуки 3 скачивал и каждая что-то да находила. Набираете топ программ для очистки от вирусов и скачиваете несколько, делая проверку.

Comment: На будущее. Есть волшебная комбинация `Alt+PrintScreen`.

Comment: Что у тебя щас в шедулере и что говорит `autoruns` Марка Русиновича про твой "реалтек"?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Realtek HD (майнер) и NT Kernel & System (троян) - вирусы, которые со временем "съедают" ваши процессор и видеокарту.

---

Перед тем как начать удаление вирусов, нажмите кнопки `Win` и `R`, запустите `Редактор реестра`. Перейдите в ветку `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windows` - удаляем все записи сайтов. Это необходимо удалить, т.к вирус записал это в реестр, чтобы мы не могли зайти на сайты где скачивают антивирусы, которые способны его удалить. Умный вирус.

---

Если и это не помогло, переходим в проводник по пути `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, находим файл `hosts`, удаляем и заново [скачиваем](https://it-like.ru/wp-content/uploads/files/hosts.zip). После этого, закидываем скачанный файл в эту же папку.
Иногда бывает, что эти 2 вируса УДАЛЯЮТ этот файл и его НУЖНО скачать и закинуть обратно.

---

Избавляемся от Realtek HD Mainer таким способом:

---

1. Скачиваем `TDSSKILLER`, запускаем.
2. Начинаем проверку системы, после чего программа находит вирусы, для каждого вируса выбираем действие `Удалить`.
3. Перезагружаем наш пк.

---

А от NT Kernel & System избавляемся таким, похожим способом:

---

1. Скачиваем `HitmanPro`, вводим свой электронный адрес.
   (ВАЖНО! - он  не требует карты или кода активации - просто даёте свой email и готово)
2. Запускаем проверку системы, это занимает больше времени чем у `TDSSKILLER`.
3. Как закончится проверка, выйдет уведомление `Для лечения пк требуется перезагрузка`, или что-то схожее. Перезагружаем, готово.
   Вирусы удалены, пк спасён.

---

P.S - Если вы удалили те записи в реестре, но сайты с антивирусами не открываются - скачайте `TDSSKILLER` и  `HitmanPro` на телефон или другой пк/ноутбук и перекиньте на вирусный пк.

---

[TDSSKILLER](https://support.kaspersky.ru/5350)

---

[HitmanPro](https://www.comss.ru/page.php?id=612)

Answer (score 0):

Все эти мороки со сканерами ни к чему, когда есть AV block remover. Информация для тех, кто заразился майнером Realtek HD Audio и зашёл на этот сайт в попытках удалить его: Посмотрите данное видео с телефона или в безопасном режиме с поддержкой сети: https://youtu.be/ianpLMzFMWQ

Если будете смотреть его с телефона, то ссылки и команды нужно будет вводить вручную на заражённом ПК!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)